# BooleanToVisibilityConverter not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, visibility, wpftoolkit

In a charting application  I'm developing, I am having trouble hiding my series. I am trying to bind the visibility  to my radio buttons IsChecked property.The charts are from WPF Toolkit. Here is the code:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="ChartSeries" Name="areaRadioButton" Content="Area Series" Margin="10,10,0,0" IsChecked="False"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="ChartSeries" Name="barRadioButton" Content="Bar Series" Margin="10,30,0,0" IsChecked="False"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="ChartSeries" Name="bubbleRadioButton" Content="Bubble Series" Margin="10,50,0,0" IsChecked="False"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="ChartSeries" Name="columnRadioButton" Content="Column Series" Margin="10,70,0,0" IsChecked="False"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="ChartSeries" Name="lineRadioButton" Content="Line Series" Margin="105,10,0,0" IsChecked="False"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="ChartSeries" Name="pieRadioButton" Content="Pie Series" Margin="105,30,0,0" IsChecked="False"/>

<chart:Chart Name="chart1">
       <chart:Chart.Series>
             <chart:ColumnSeries Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=columnRadioButton,Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartItems}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
             <chart:PieSeries Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=pieRadioButton, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartItems}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
       </chart:Chart.Series>
</chart:Chart>
```

And I have declared my boolean to visibility converter as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Firstly switch your Custom `Chart` Control to something basic like say a `Button` and see if the problem still persists. If it works fine, your issue is elsewhere in your custom control than the Converter  which would be my bet.

Comment: It seems to work, are you sure your datacontext is correctly set?

Comment: @Pragmateek What DataContext? The Visibility Bindings already have their ElementName set.

Comment: I was talking about the *ChartItems* binding. I've tested your code and it works, at least when you correctly set the **DataContext** so that *ChartItems* is accessible. Try to display them in a ListBox to be fixed.

Comment: Can you post your converter, it seems that's the only thing that is missing in your question for us to see.

Comment: @Djerry the converter is the one provided by the .NET framework. Plase see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

Comment: @darkArk: if you remove the visibility property from 1 of the chart series (so either column or pie), do you see that chart with the data you get from "chartitems"?

Comment: @Djerry: If I remove the visibility binding I can still see the chart. Anyway I have solved this issue, I have declared a bool property for each series and I have binded both the radio buttons and the chartSeries to them and it works. Anyhow, very strange..